# Architecture diagram explaining the Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure with MAAS / Openstack architecture?

Tags: juju, documentation, openstack, maas

I'm interested in Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure with MAAS (based on Openstack from what I understand) but **cannot find any architecture diagram which gives an overview of how MAAS** works.

The case is **Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure** with **MAAS**.

It requires at least 10 nodes (as described in [Installing Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-cloud#cloud-infra)) and this "10 MAAS nodes architecture" would typically be a perfect candidate for an architecture diagram!

Wouldn't it be an easy/reality-based way to understand how MAAS works and what it offers?

Looking for docs, I stumbled upon a technical and up-to-date documentation with architecture diagrams(!): [Revisiting OpenStack Architecture: Essex Edition](http://ken.pepple.info/openstack/2012/02/21/revisit-openstack-architecture-diablo/)

---

*Could we imagine that an architecture diagram and/or description could be provided to easily understand how a minimal 10 nodes Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure with MAAS installation works?*

Comment: Another (not so) old documentation: [OpenStack Project Architecture Overview](http://docs.openstack.org/cactus/openstack-compute/admin/content/openstack-architecture-overview.html) but it's based on a previous Openstack release (named "Cactus")

Comment: Note that it's mainly the "cloud" part (with OpenStack) which should be described. The fact that MAAS is a PXE deploying server on steroids and that juju is used to deploy charms (one service per node) is pretty straightforward. But what OpenStack brings with a distributed storage for cloud - see [OpenStack Object Storage: An Overview](http://openstack.org/downloads/openstack-object-storage-datasheet.pdf) for example - is another story: this is what should be described by a diagram. I hope my question is more clear this way.

Comment: Maybe a first step would be to list what is the role of each 10 machines of the [Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure deployment with MAAS and Juju](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Deploying_Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_Juju): 1) `MAAS server` 2) `juju bootstrap node` (Juju uses it to coordinate the services being deployed) 3) `mysql` 4) openstack's `rabbitmq` 5) openstack's `keystone` 6) openstack's `nova-cloud-controller` 7) openstack's `nova-volume` 8) openstack's `nova-compute` 9) openstack's `glance` 10) openstack's `openstack-dashboard`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am in the process of designing a system to deploy MaaS/Juju/Openstack/juju-jitsu.  The diagram below displays the architecture that I think is necessary for the minimum install as specified by the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure).  I have also been working on a juju overview document found [here](http://ubuntuone.com/6tpNPoFaZxZFYFbjiJyEaM).

[image: Architecture Diagram for MaaS/Juju/Openstack/juju-jitsu]

Note 1: I found this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176498/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-nodes-for-an-ubuntu-cloud) useful in determining the configuration for the 6 MaaS node architecture.  To get the 10 node based architecture, the diagram can be expanded to have one server per node.

Note 2: For the 6 node architecture, the minimum number of physical computers is 7.

Note 3: For the 10 node architecture, the minimum number of physical computers is: 11.

Answer (score 7):

if someone deploys maas+juju for openstack, please run `juju status --format=png > architecture.png`

Comment: This is not available on `precise` (juju version `1.20.1-precise-amd64`)