# What is the minimum number of nodes for an Ubuntu Cloud?

Tags: maas

What is the minimum number of nodes required to setup a functioning cloud as described in this tutorial:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure

I just want to run some tests and I don't have 10 computers lying around to do so. Is it possible to use 2-3 nodes(+1 for the MAAS server)?

Answer (score 2):

Each time `juju deploy` is called it starts a new machine. Also, `juju bootstrap` reserves a machine to start up zookeeper.

So it looks like that example needs about 9 nodes.

Since you don't have 10 machines, you could do the simple example [here](https://juju.ubuntu.com/Documentation).

Comment: That link to the simple example is ... well not quite dead but not exactly leading to any example :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use juju-jitsu to set the same in 6 machines.

In this case, glance and dashboard goes on same machine as keystone and rabbitmq-server goes along with mysql server. Thus you save 3 machines.

Arminder

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you might be able to get away with the MAAS server itself (1), add two nodes to that (2,3) and then lump up several services on the first actual node itself using the following syntax:

```
juju deploy --to lxc:0 keystone
juju deploy --to lxc:0 rabbitmq-server
juju deploy --to lxc:0 nova-cloud-controller
juju deploy --to lxc:0 openstack-dashboard
juju deploy --to lxc:0 glance
juju deploy --to lxc:0 juju-gui
juju deploy --to lxc:0 cinder
...etc...
juju deploy --to lxc:1 nova-compute
```

I'm assuming an install of Ubuntu, MAAS, JuJu and OpenStack.  You probably want to deploy ceph to there.  Depending upon the network situation you may want to add the neutron-related stuff.  Possibly you might want memcached.

If you look at the charms page for the openstack base you get an idea of what would be included by default:  https://jujucharms.com/openstack-base/36  If you use this openstack base charm, though, it will deploy to one service per node, methinks.  If you walk juju through its paces manually though and take advantage of the syntax I've described you can "co-locate" services on the same box.

See the following video:  [Deploy openstack to two servers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59lVKD3VCEQ).  Be forgiving of the first ten minutes of the video as the author flounders a bit.  He eventually gets down to the good stuff by the end.